# Fetch data with axios and export to a component as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am naive in react and i am struggling with a simple stuff, needing your help.
All i need to do is to pass array of value from external service as prop to another

## Approach

```
render() {
    let todolist="default";
   axios.get('http://localhost:8888/todoitems').then(function(res){
            todolist=res.data;
          });
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="text" ref="newvalue"/>
         <button onClick={this.save}>Submit</button>
            <TodoList data={todolist} />
      </div>

    );
  }
```

What happens is, "default" is getting as this.props.data instead of response from external service.

Moreover, i get "Cannot set property 'state' of undefined when i try to set as state.Like below:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        axios.get('http://localhost:8888/todoitems').then(function(res){
            this.state={
              data:res.data;
            }
          });
        }
```

Please help .

Comment: this naive approach cannot work.. because of the async / sync nature

Comment: You should try it with `state` and some of the components life cycle methods like `componentWillMount`

Comment: use `this.setState`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your API request shouldn't be present in the render method since everytime you component updates, the render method is called and hence you API request is made again. You should make your API requests in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and then update the state with the response which you can use in the render method. If you need to fire your API request at regular intervals, place it inside a `setInterval` method. P.S. Don't forget to clear the interval timer in the `componentWillUnmount` function

```
state = {
    todoList: "default"
}
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8888/todoitems').then((res) => {
            this.setState({todolist: res.data})
          });
}
render() {


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="text" ref="newvalue"/>
         <button onClick={this.save}>Submit</button>
            <TodoList data={this.state.todolist} />
      </div>

    );
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the error, the problem was binding in the axios request callback, use arrow functions instead. Updated the answer

Comment: @Shubham you should use an `arrow function` in the resolver

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks so much folks!

Answer (score 2):

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8888/todoitems').then(function(res) {
    todolist=res.data;
});
```

The above piece of code is executed asynchronously. It does not pause the execution of the `render()` method. When the `render()` method reaches that code it makes a call to server and then immediately processes to return the JSX without waiting for the response from server.

I have seen many developers taking this approach. Maybe you should give it a try too.

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {todolist: "default"};
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8888/todoitems').then((res) => {
        this.setState({todolist: res.data});
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="text" ref="newvalue"/>
            <button onClick={this.save}>Submit</button>
            <TodoList data={this.state.todolist} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! arrow function helped!